# Updating a MySQLi database using php and HTML5 forms

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli, sql-update

On my website i have an admin page where i want to be able to update information in the database, using a form.

This is the code im using to enter information and update what is in my database:

adminform.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

<header id="header">
                <h1><a href="home.php">SafeTNet</a></h1>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>

                        <li>Admin Page Only</li>
                        <li></li>


                        <li><a href="logout.php" class="button">Logout</a>    </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

 <h1> Select a member </h1>
 <br />
 <select name="members" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option value="">Select a member email</option>
 <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','SafeTNetD');
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    echo '<option value="'.$row["email"].'">'.$row["email"].'</option>';
 ?>
 </select>
    <div id="signup">
       <h2>Update Your Member Information</h2>
        <form method="post" action="admin1.php">
           <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
         <tr> 
            <td>City </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="submit">
        </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

admin1.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
 </head>  
 <body>


<header id="header">
                <h1><a href="home.php">SafeTNet</a></h1>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>

                        <li>Admin Page Only</li>
                        <li></li>


                        <li><a href="logout.php" class="button">Logout</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
    <br />

 <?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM members";
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','SafeTNetD');
 $result = $mysqli->query($query);
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 echo '<option value="'.$row["email"].'">'.$row["email"].'</option>';
 ?>
</select>
<br />
<?php
$q=$row["email"];
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','members');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$q."'";
if(array_key_exists('_submit_check', $_POST))
{
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $city = $_POST['city'];

$sql = "UPDATE members SET city = '$city' WHERE email = '$q'";
if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo 'Record updated successfully<br />';
}
    else
{
    echo $sql.'<br />' . $mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

```
<br><br><br>

<footer id="footer">
                <img src="logo.jpg" height="50px">

                <ul class="copyright">
                    <li>&copy; SafeTNet. All rights reserved.</li><li> 2016</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the form to run but cant get the information to change in the database or echo to the screen.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array_key_exists('_submit_check', $_POST))
{
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $city = $_POST['city'];

$sql = "UPDATE members SET city = '$city' WHERE email = '$q'";
if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo 'Record updated successfully<br />';
}
    else
{
    echo $sql.'<br />' . $mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
}
```

There is no element called '_submit_check' in your form. I guess you forgot the name attribute of your submit-button.

Your script is very vulnerable to SQL-Injection. You really should not simply throw the userinput into your query. You can use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli-stmt.php%20Prepared%20Statements) to protect your application.

To improve the readability of your code you could change the structure a little. In your admin1.php you should do the business logic before outputting any html. So you would first check if the form has been sent, then you do the database operation. The result of the check or the success/error-message of the database operation can be written into a variable until you output the content of your site.

This way everybody who starts reading the code immediately knows 'alright, this script is the target of some form and accesses the database for some write-operation'.